# Collecting user information for debugging and support

Tags: privacy

I have a Java application that I need to support. I'd like it to collect user information, such as system information: OS and hardware for easier diagnostics and support.

- Are there any security & privacy regulations I need to follow?
- Do I specifically need consent from the user to do this?

Answer (score 5):

**In short:** It is mandatory to get consent of the users. The application should get user consent and acknowledge them about the information that is gathered. Because, by different country laws not disclosing this activity is **considered to be crime.**

**Disclaimer :** I am not a lawyer, and you may probably would need to contact a lawyer who would advice you on exact procedures and "disclaimer terms" that you should have in place.

However, generally speaking the application should have **Terms and Conditions** that users need to accept, in order to be able to use the systems.

There are related discussion on this topic that you may look for [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13041631/1437962).

For example: StackExchange has the following [**disclaimer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27362/stack-overflow-no-terms-and-conditions) in place.

Answer (score 0):

Need: depends on the country you and your users are in. Ask a lawyer.

Should you explicitly gain consent to avoid pissing off users who will think you are scum when they find out you've been doing it without permisssion: Yes. Absolutely. Essential. Oh dear $diety yes. What, are you crazy? Just do it. And so on, you get the idea.